# Blurry SVGs in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg

My SVG graphics are not rendering crisply in Firefox.  For example, the following should produce a 14px x 14px square with a 2px stroke width:

```
<svg width='14' height='14'><rect x='1' y='1' width='12' height='12' stroke='black' stroke-width='2' fill='transparent'/></svg>
```

Firefox usually produces a square with antialiased edges.  This can be seen in the following jsfiddle.  In fact, when I resize the browser window, the fuzziness changes: sometimes it appears crisp and sometimes it gets fuzzy.

http://jsfiddle.net/auq8x3ce/

Chrome and Safari draw the SVGs fine.  I've only seen this happen in Firefox.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the reason but I can point you out a solution, force anti-aliasing by making all the points defining the rectangle with .5 values, x and y, just by making the origin to 1.5 instead of 1 (0.5 wont work because the stroke-width is 2)

Comment: You could try css shape-rendering: crispEdges see if it makes any difference. I can't reproduce the problem in Firefox 26.0 here